# Where should I insert "etags -R ." in makefile?

Tags: makefile, ocaml, etag

I am writing a compiler in Ocaml...

I am just wondering at which stage it is most convenient to generate the `tags`... I guess it should not be after the compilation of all files, because it is possible that the compilation fails, and it still makes sense to get `tags`.

Where do you usually put `etags` in makefile?

Answer (score 1):

I put tag generation on a separate target. When I want to generate an executable, I don't care about tags. When I'm working on the source code, I might want to regenerate the tags even if I know my code won't compile right now.

Comment: I think this is the best behaviour. Automake-generated makefiles do this, providing `tags` and `TAGS` targets for this purpose.