# why `-R` after `-L` in Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++

I saw `-L/home/kgbook/tools/libiconv/lib -liconv -R/home/kgbook/tools/libiconv/lib` when `make VERBOSE=1`.

What's the meaning of `-R`, I saw nothing when `gcc --help` or `man gcc`. No `-R` option or argument, neither `gcc` nor `g++`.

And why we need `-R/home/kgbook/tools/libiconv/lib` after `-L/home/kgbook/tools/libiconv/lib -liconv`?

I'm still confused after saw the question 
[Where should I insert "etags -R ." in makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195412/where-should-i-insert-etags-r-in-makefile).

Comment: `-R` here is a linker option, `gcc` doesn't understand it directly and has no help on it. You need to look into `ld` documentation for it. `-R` of `etags` is completely unrelated.

Comment: you are right. `-R FILE, --just-symbols FILE
                              Just link symbols (if directory, same as --rpath)`, thanks you.